# How can I eliminate this "jumping effect" on my button when using an inline floating-label text input?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Any elements which are inline with an input that has a floating label (Bootstrap 5) will seemingly jump up and down depending on the position of the floating label.

[image: GIF of jumping effect]

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div>
  <h3 style="display:inline">Example Header</h3>
  <div style="display:inline-block; margin-left:35px" class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
    <input style="width:auto" type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
  </div>
  <button style="display:inline" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Press</button>
</div>
```

I would like to keep the input element inline with the button, without the button being *relative* to the floating label.

I've tried applying `position: absolute` on the input, and as expected, that solves the issue because it no longer is relative to the things that it is inline with. Unfortunately, I *need* to avoid the position being absolute because I actually want the position of the button to be relative to the input. Just not the floating label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the input groups that Bootstrap has:

- [Input groups docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/input-group/#button-addons)
- [Floating label input groups docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/floating-labels/#input-groups)

When using a group, only try and add any custom styles and margin classes on that outer-most element and not on any of the inner elements

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="input-group mb-3 mt-3" style="margin-left:35px">
  <div class="form-floating">
    <input style="width:auto" type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Press</button>
</div>
```

---

EDIT: or just use [the flexbox utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/flex/) to have separated buttons

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="mb-3 mt-3 d-flex" style="margin-left:35px">
    <div class="form-floating">
      <input style="width:auto" type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
    </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ms-1 align-self-end">Press</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is neat, but the button in your example almost looks like it is a part of the text input field. I was hoping to get it to appear like the one in my example, and just get rid of the jumping effect. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: I also might want to put other elements, such as headers (or anything that isn't an input), **inline** with these input groups. So I don't think this would work, because the headers would still have the jumping effect. I'll edit my question to include an inline header.

Comment: If you run my code snippet now, you should see what I mean.

Comment: @Caleb OK, see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks! I'm not seeing information on `ms-1` in the documentation that you provided, and I can't seem to find anything on it in the BS docs. Seems like it has something to do with margins but I don't know. Would you mind briefly explaining why you included `ms-1`?

Comment: Sure, that's in the [spacing docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/spacing/#notation).  `m` is for "margin", `s` is for "start".  Bootstrap uses start/end instead of left/right because it's easier to support RTL languages so you can have the same code used for both languages if needed.